# Is their a way to integrate Drupal-8 and ionic4 for user registration and login?

Tags: php, mysql, ionic4, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal 8 and I am working on a project for my company please help with this issue.

we have registration from in the ionic app and we want to send the data to Drupal 8 site MySQL DB.

the problem is that when we created the registration form in Drupal 8 using multiple registration module is created for each field in the form a separate table in the database for example username field has its own table.

how can we insert the data from our app into Drupal DB to allow users to register either from the app or the website?

we are using multiple registration module in Drupal 8.

I have tried using an in-app browser (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) to embed the form within our app but it shows the whole page with header and footer which we do not want.

I also have tried to send the data as a JSON file and from their inserting data into tables using PHP and MySQL commands but this is a very long and difficult task.

```js
let headers: any = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
       options: any = { "key": "create",
      'id': obj.id,
       'fullName': obj.fullName,
       'email': obj.email,
       'idNumber': obj.idNumber,
       'gender': obj.gender,
       'age': obj.age,
       'phone': obj.phone,
       'status': obj.status,
       'qualifications': obj.qualifications,
       'skills': obj.skills[0],
       'city': obj.city,
       'terms': obj.terms,
     },

this.http.post(url2, JSON.stringify(options), headers)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log('successfully added');
      },
        (error: any) => {
          console.log('Something went wrong!', error);
        });
```

and for inserting data

```php
// Retrieve the posted data
   $json    =  file_get_contents('php://input');
   $obj     =  json_decode($json);
   $key     =  strip_tags($obj->key);

   switch($key)
   {
     case "createTest":
  $field_mdynt_alskn_target_id = filter_var($obj->field_mdynt_alskn_target_id, 
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
  $field_username_value   = filter_var($obj->field_altk_al_value, 
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);

           try {
            $sql    = "INSERT INTO user_name(field_username_value) VALUES(:field_username_value)";
            $stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':field_mdynt_alskn_target_id', $field_mdynt_alskn_target_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);     
$stmt->execute();

            echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Congratulations the record ' . $name . ' was added to the database'));
         }
         // Catch any errors in running the prepared statement
         catch(PDOException $e)
         {
            echo $e->getMessage();
         }

      break;
```

here the issue is that each field has its own table in the database for example username field has the table user_name and the same for all fields in the form and me to do the same for all fields which I guess not the correct way to do.

is there a faster and efficient way to insert the data from our ionic 4 app registration form to the database of our Drupal site.

thank you and let me know in case; further clarification is required..

**just to clarify:**

we installed **"Multiple registration pages module"** and then used ***"Drupal/admin/people/roles"*** to create different users as in the following image

[image]

then added fields for each role using ***"Drupal/admin/config/people/accounts/fields"*** 
as in this image 
[image]

[image]
and that caused Drupal to create each field with its table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

First fix the Database architecture, a table for every form field is not going to be efficient and scalable.

I doubt if any Drupal extension does that, if it does, it should be kicked out of the drupal universe.

you can see from this image how many tables we have for the users [image]

Comment: thank you @Zeeshan Chawdhary for you respnse,, well we used multiple registration so we can have different roles for the users and we added the fields to the form based on the user role lets say providers and consumers for example.    and the form works fine but in the database there are too many tables where each belong to a specific field.. i have never experienced such any thing like this before that is why i am kind lost.

Answer (score 0):

The option that I would be looking into is to make a page template that has a stripped-back design that you can embed the same way you tried originally.

If you can't figure out how to get Drupal to serve a custom template for a single page, then I would write some JavaScript or CSS to just delete/hide all the page components I didn't want to be seen when embedded in the app.

You can add a query string parameter, or make a second page with the form on so that you can detect when it needs the design changing.

As you have already discovered, trying to do it manually is complicated and not a task I would like to take on unless I was already an expert in that particular area.

I don't know if you have considered the full user experience though? What will happen after the user has registered? You will just end up with a completed form, but the app will not know it is registered, because that will have happened on the server. I think JWT would be the direction to start researching but I don't have a simple solution that I can suggest.

Comment: i tried using a page template as you mentioned but i got an error about something related to "X-Frame Options" that is Refused to display a frame and i have no idea where the issue is.  can you please direct me to a good resource for JWT tutorial or an example related to drupal i have looked everywhere and found nothing.    we want to allow users to register from the app as if they are registering from the web. do you suggest we use different technology rather than drupal if so what do you suggest.